# xymatrix: Arrows badly placed when used with large nodes

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I find that using `xymatrix` with large nodes results in awkwardly placed arrows:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\textbf{Natural Numbers}
\ar@/_/[r]  &\textbf{Integers} \ar@/_/[l]
}
\end{document}
```

Suggestions on placing these more elegantly would be gratefully received.

(If at all possible, I would prefer solutions that used `xymatrix`. I have a number of diagrams using `xymatrix`, most of which are unproblematic, and I would prefer not to have to convert them all to e.g. `tikz`.)

Note that the `xymatrix` manual has information on changing the target of an arrow, but not the source... and here it is the source ends that are problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the final product you have in mind but one of these can be selected (I don't know how to select the correct direction for the arrow head):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\textbf{Natural Numbers} \ar@(ul,ur)[r] &\textbf{Integers} \ar@/^5mm/[l]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textbf{Natural Numbers}\ar@/^5.5mm/[r]  &\textbf{Integers} \ar@/^5mm/[l]` works nicely, with no arrow-head correction needed.